# callback on function from other class

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I have customView and and there is `UITextField`, and in my `ViewController`, I am using a lot of this views. So in `customView.swift` I have `UITextFieldDelegate`. But I want to do some actions on this callback in my `ViewController`. Example : 
when I tap on textfield, delegate executes

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    println("delegate")
}
```

and after this I want some function that works with ViewController UI to execute, example:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        println("delegate")
        ViewController().check()
}
```

But it gets nil, so I want to create some callback, can you advise right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom property of type `ViewController` in your `customView` class. In the `viewDidLoad` function of `ViewController`, call

```
theCustomView.viewController = self
```

(where theCustomView is the instance - you probably have a reference to this as well, otherwise create an IBOutlet)

Then, in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function you can just use

```
self.viewController.check()
```